# How change component background color

Tags: css, sapui5, openurl

I would like emphatize items changing the backgroud color.
In Particular I have a page with `sap.uxap.ObjectPageHeader` and a list with `sap.m.ObjectListItem`.

I want change the header backround and the list item background with `@sapUiWarningBG` color (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.BasicThemeParameters/preview)

If, for example, I try to set the header background by `class` property, it doesn't work..

```
<ux:ObjectPageHeader
    class="sapUiWarningBG"
    objectImageURI="sap-icon://database">
```

How can I obtain the result?

Answer (score 0):

You try to use the theme parameter `@sapUiWarningBG` as style class. This does not work! You can think of theme parameters as variables which are used to define recurring values, e.g. background color. These variables can be used in your CSS classes. The final CSS is created by a CSS pre-processor, [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) in this case. Please check the [documentation](https://help.hana.ondemand.com/theme_designer/frameset.htm?895a4b03cf664b79976d12f019c68b12.html) how to add custom CSS.

However, I strongly recommend to use the existing features to visualize the warning, e.g. by using an object status with state "Warning". You find extensive examples in the [documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.uxap.sample.ObjectPageHeaderWithAllControls/preview).